# JSON-simple. Добавить объект в массив и прочитать

Tags: java, json

К примеру надо записать просто строки:

```
JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject();
outputJson.put("id", "1");
```

Получаем:

```
{"id":"1"}
```

Записать массив:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add("auto");
outputJson.put("car",list);
```

Получаем:

```
{ "car":["auto"]}
```

А как записать и главное прочитать вот такое:

```
{
"car": [{
    "id": "auto"
}, {
    "id": "auto2"
}]
```

}

Т.е в массив вписать произвольное кол-во объектов и потом их считать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записать так:

```
    JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    //Делаем первый элемент id
    JSONObject id1 = new JSONObject();
    id1.put("id", "auto");
    //Делаем второй элемент id
    JSONObject id2 = new JSONObject();
    id2.put("id", "auto2");
    //Добавляем их в наш массив
    list.add(id1);
    list.add(id2);
    //Добавляем в главный
    outputJson.put("car", list);
```

Прочитать так:

```
    String json = "{\"car\":[{\"id\":\"auto\"},{\"id\":\"auto2\"}]}";
    //Преобразуем в объект
    JSONObject inputJson = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
    //Получаем список id
    JSONArray ids = (JSONArray) inputJson.get("car");
```

Ну и вывод элементов `(JSONObject) ids.get(0)` и т.д.

Также вывод можно сделать через цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println((JSONObject) ids.get(i));
}
```

Результат получаем следующий:

```
Входной JSON -> {"car":[{"id":"auto"},{"id":"auto2"}]}
Выходные элементы: {"id":"auto"} , {"id":"auto2"}
```

Comment: А как получить доступ к конкретному полю?  Что бы не в таком формате как сейчас выводит. Если поле не одно к примеру, а надо считать только конкретное.

Comment: Сделал так:
    JSONArray ids = (JSONArray) person.get("test");
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) ids.get(i);
        String D = (String) temp.get("DDR");
        String M = (String) temp.get("Memory");
        
        System.out.println("1: "+D+M);
        
       @Chubatiy, спасибо за помощь.
       }